# Is there any guide to get PDF or Excel files from sharepoint with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sharepoint

I need to create an API with NodeJs, Express, and Typescript, to get some files either PDF or Excel that are inside a folder in a Sharepoint, however as much as I have searched I can not find a guide to help me create this project, anyone knows or can tell me where to look to create this API?

I googled, but no related articles

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

First install the library axios in you project.

```
npm install axios
```

Then create nodejs script `file-fetch.js`:

Note : replace your `sharepointSiteUrl` , `username` , `password`  and `filePath`

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');

const sharepointSiteUrl = '<your_sharepoint_site>';
const username = '<your_username>';
const password = '<your_password>';
const filePath = '<file_path>'; // e.g., '/sites/your-site/Shared Documents/Your Folder/yourfile.pdf'or excel

// Function to authenticate with SharePoint
async function getAuthToken() {
    const authUrl = `${sharepointSiteUrl}/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=sharepoint&scope=fullcontrol`;
    const response = await axios.post(authUrl, `username=${username}&password=${password}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
    return response.data;
}

// Function to download a file from SharePoint
async function downloadFile(authToken) {
    const fileUrl = `${sharepointSiteUrl}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('${filePath}')/$value`;
    const response = await axios.get(fileUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'responseType': 'arraybuffer',
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        })
    });

    // Save the file locally
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, response.data);

    console.log(`File downloaded: ${fileName}`);
}

// Main function
async function main() {
    try {
        const authToken = await getAuthToken();
        await downloadFile(authToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
}

main();
```

Finally, run the script with node :

```
node file-fetch.js
```